# JQueryMobile Open phone gallery and select an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

is possible to open the native gallery of a phone  (iOs, Android,Windows Phone etc...)and select an image with jQueryMobile? and if how?

Tnks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem with HTML5 form, because it's impossible for javascript to accede to the file system.